# JS CSS border-bottom on auto-complete results

Tags: css, html, scrollbars, border

This might be hard to show exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, so please bear with me.

I have an auto-complete result box I am having trouble style properly.

Here there are 2 divs:

```
<div id="SearchResultsContainer">
<div id="SearchResults">

</div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#SearchResults {
    border: 2px solid #666;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#SearchResultsContainer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 54%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: none;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
```

Ok, now for the problem.  With this styling, the inner SearchResults div styles the border.  This is fine if there are say 2 results.

When there is overflow-y, the bottom border disappears until the user scrolls to the bottom.

If I add the border-bottom to SearchResultsContainer, the border is placed at the bottom of the 200px high SearchResultsContainer, regardless of how many results there are so it looks like a floating line across the screen..

What is the best way to handle the border bottom?  I found a few methods on google to determine if the scrollbars are active on the div, but is there a more eligant way to handle the bottom border?

I hope I explained the problem well enough, if not please ask!

Thanks

Comment: oh rats... this is probably not helpful, but I don't have time atm (got to pay attention in this class :P).  Here's a demo of what I think you are trying to do roughly? http://jsfiddle.net/R3nWN/

Comment: Sort of.  For some reason on that jsfiddle SearchResultsContainer is only 2 results high.  Try making it 5 results high, but populate it with 2 results. lol you sound like me @ school :p

Comment: Here is what my problem looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/guyfromfl/xwgzx/  if you remove some of the text x's in the html it will look ok, but once you over flow, the bottom border disappears.

Comment: I see what you're saying... are you by any chance needing a max-hight div like in this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/6bbQT/

Comment: Thanks Joseph, thats it!  I knew I didn't have to get into JS to do it... Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: You're welcome :) I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the functionality desired is to have the border expand with the content until a certain point and then make the content scrollable.  This can be accomplished with the `max-height` attribute.

```
max-height:150px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6bbQT/